# Нужно пройти по коллекции объектов и суммировать значения поля если совпадает дата. Использовать Stream API

Tags: java, коллекции, потоки-данных, java-stream

Нужно скомпоновать `HashMap<LocalDate, Integer>` из коллекции объектов, которые имеют поля `LocalDateTime localDateTime` и `int calories`.

Я написал такой код без использования Stream API:

```
HashMap<LocalDate, Integer> mapDateAndCalories = new HashMap<>();

LocalDate localDate = meals.get(0).getDateTime().toLocalDate();
int calories = 0;
for (UserMeal um: meals) {
    LocalDate localDateForEach = um.getDateTime().toLocalDate();
    if (localDate.equals(localDateForEach)) {
        calories += um.getCalories();
    } else {
        mapDateAndCalories.put(localDate, calories);
        calories = um.getCalories();
        localDate = localDateForEach;
    }
}
mapDateAndCalories.put(localDate, calories);
```

Есть коллекция `meals`, у неё в записях может быть сколько угодно приёмов пищи с одинаковой датой, но разным временем (`LocalDataTime`) и полем `calories` (количество калорий за один приём пищи).

Нужно получить коллекцию `map`, где ключ - это дата `LocalDate` (год и день в году), а значение - это сумма всех калорий за этот день.

Предварительно отсортировав коллекцию `meals` в порядке возрастания по дате, я её прохожу, и если дата записи совпадает с предыдущей, то суммирую значение поля `calories` в одну переменную, если значение даты поменялось (следующий день), то записываю в `hashmap` то, что нассумировал, т.е. ключ у меня это год и день в году, а значение сумма калорий за этот день. Далее суммирую уже следующий день и т.д.

Так вот собственно вопрос, как написать такую же логику, но используя Stream API?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь нужно использовать [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) для группировки по дате и [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) для суммирования калорий (в данном случае можно использовать ссылку на метод `UserMeal::getCalories`):

```java
Map<LocalDate, Integer> mapDateAndCalories = meals
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        meal -> meal.getDateTime().toLocalDate(), // ключ LocalDate
        Collectors.summingInt(UserMeal::getCalories)
    ));
```

---

Также, если результат должен быть упорядочен по дате, можно использовать вариант [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) с параметром `Supplier<Map<K, V>>`.  Если входной список `meals` уже отсортирован, можно использовать `LinkedHashMap::new`; также можно обойтись без предварительной сортировки `meals`, если "собирать" результат в `TreeMap` при помощи `TreeMap::new`:

```java
Map<LocalDate, Integer> mapDateAndCalories = meals
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        meal -> meal.getDateTime().toLocalDate(), // ключ LocalDate
        LinkedHashMap::new, // сохранить порядок входного отсортированного списка
        Collectors.summingInt(UserMeal::getCalories)
    ));

SortedMap<LocalDate, Integer> sortedMapDateAndCalories = meals
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        meal -> meal.getDateTime().toLocalDate(), // ключ LocalDate
        TreeMap::new, // если входной список неотсортирован
        Collectors.summingInt(UserMeal::getCalories)
    ));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отлично работает!

Comment: Спасибо, что напомнили, ещё не до конца разобрался с навигацией стэковерфлоу ))